# react-query and selectors and architecture

Tags: react-query

I am removing some very intertwined global state from a new app (redux/sagas/selectors), to -> context api and react-query. There are tons of selectors integrated into this "global state", that is now needing to be refactored. I've only put a few, co-locating them with the mutations that generate the required data. BUT --

What are your strategies of using "selectors" with react-query?

Where are you locating these selectors, in the component folder or in a "selectors" folder, or sitting within the react-query useQuery in which the data is derived?

So, just to be clear, I am using the new react-query selector functionality. My legacy APP has selectors globally & in the components proper, and I am not sure that is the clearest way.. also, especially if I have a useQuery wrapper sitting globally... just trying to sort out the architecture here.

Any help is appreciated.

Note: I guess we could have a "selectors" file (co-located) with the feature, but do we then import the useQuery hook I have and just do it there.. in a "selectors.ts" file IN the feature folder it is used in..... OR move the selectors INTO the useQuery wrapper hook file.

1. What if these selectors are feature dependent (no other feature/part of the is gonna need them?).
2. What if these selectors can be used globally?

Strategies?

Comment: Do you really mean useMutation or useQuery, because only useQuery has selectors…

Comment: useQuery... i edited. I had mutation on the brain cause I was just working on one :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally try to keep as little things as possible global - mostly things co-located within a certain feature. If something really needs to be accessible everywhere in the app, it's likely it's own feature. If there is a single query that needs to be used in multiple features, I do have a top level `queries` directory where they are, but there is really not much in there.

As for selectors: I inline them in the useQuery hook, if I need them more than once, I extract them to a function, and if that's get out of hand, I put them in a separate file next to the queries, like:

```
- features
  - todos
    - queries.ts
    - selectors.ts
```

nothing fancy just going with whatever Kent C. Dodds recommends :) https://kentcdodds.com/blog/colocation

Comment: Is a feature supposed to be accessible to other features? I have trouble with the definition of a "feature" in this context to be honest.. For example queries related to the user. Say there is a page for updating the user you are logged in as. And then there is a user admin page where an admin can update another user. Would both these functions be within the same feature? Or should the user queries be made global and used by these separate "features"?

Comment: it's not an easy thing to answerd. The best features are the one that are truly isolated. The ones that don't break anything if you delete them :) We also have features that depend on other features, so it's not always avoidable. If you have queries that are needed by multiple features, I would make them global